# Firebase react-native iOS build fails with "-fobjc-weak is not supported on the current deployment target"

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, react-native-ios

If I try to run my react-native app from XCode, xcode fails with the message:

> -fobjc-weak is not supported on the current deployment target

If I run from a shell `react-native run-ios`, then I get also an error message:

> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
>       CompileC /Users/michel/Development/Androdev/Firebase/Sample/FlightLogIos/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/nanopb-dummy.o Target\ Support\ Files/nanopb/nanopb-dummy.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>
> (1 failure)

However, the app still runs. It is annoying though as I think I will have at some point to do some Objective C code for my project. Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [-fobjc-weak is not supported on the current deployment target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48643389/fobjc-weak-is-not-supported-on-the-current-deployment-target)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same problem with my ionic app, and I did this steps:

1. Close xcode
2. Command line remove ios platform
3. Command line add ios platform
4. Open xcode and open PROJECT.xcworkspaces
5. Xcode give me some recommendations in project and apply
6. Clean and build and it's works

I hope this helps

Comment: This worked but I only had to go to the nanopb as mentioned by Vladimir. I had to dig a bit, because it does not suggest directly to change the target, it just showed the error being in nanobp. Before doing as you said, I had never seen nanobp. Thanks to both of you guys.

Comment: How you do that please give the clear solution. I'm getting this issue also

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Firebase in a regular, non-react-native Xcode project. I had the same error when building nanopb target. When I checked settings, deployment target for nanopb was set to 4.3. Just updating it to something more recent, like 9.0 fixed this error for me.

Comment: Thanks, Vladimir. I could not find nanobp directly on my open project, but following Adexe's approach, it became clear where to find it.

Answer (score 1):

i just ran into the same problem. i fixed it for me by increasing the ios deployment target of the nanopb target to iOS 8.0 (its 4.3 per default). Pods Project -> target: nanopb -> iOS Deployment Target: iOS 8.0