# -fobjc-weak is not supported on the current deployment target

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, grpc, boringssl

I just updated my Pods and one of them `BoringSSL` is now eroring my build with following error:

```
Apple LLVM 9.0 Error
-fobjc-weak is not supported on the current deployment target
```

Not sure about what I need to do here? Is this an issue with `BoringSSL` package or my project?

*EDIT* I believe this is used by `grpc` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [CocoaPods/Xcodeproj#544](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/issues/544) for which a fix was released recently.

Update the Xcodeproj gem from 1.5.5 to 1.5.6.

Comment: I see, since I am a new user to cocoapods would you mind giving a detailed guide on updating Xcodeproj gem?

Comment: `gem update xcodeproj` may work, but it depends upon how ruby and CocoaPods are installed.